# JavaScript - Filtering an index of an array with .includes()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to filter out array `data` and have my return be `newData` filtering out the index that includes the title "Tourism"

I am using the `.filter` method and using `.includes` but when doing so newData return value includes "Tourism" even though I putting a check to return all values that does not include this.

Here is a code example of what I am working with :

```js
let data = [ { title: "Vacation", revenue: 23421 }, { title: "Hospitals", revenue: 34212 }, { title: "Tourism", revenue: 42124 }, {title: "International Tourism", revenue: 87321 } ]


newData = data.filter(function (item) {
  return !item.title.includes('Tourism') || item.title.includes('Vacation')
})

console.log(newData)
```

I am expecting the returning values to not include `"Tourism" and "International Tourism"` based off the `.includes`  returning everything that does not include "Tourism". Am I approaching this scenario the correct way? My current value is returning everything within the array regardless of my `.includes` check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` is a **method**, so it is a function which takes an argument, specifically the value to check for in the string or array it is called on. Use `.includes(value)` instead:

```js
let data = [{
  title: "Vacation",
  revenue: 23421
}, {
  title: "Hospitals",
  revenue: 34212
}, {
  title: "Tourism",
  revenue: 42124
}, {
  title: "International Tourism",
  revenue: 87321
}];

newData = data.filter(
  item => !item.title.includes('Tourism')
);

console.log(newData);
```

For your edit, if you want to filter out multiple values, you can use a few ways to say the same thing. Consider `!includesTitle() && !includesVacation()` ("doesn't include title and doesn't include vacation") and `!(includesTitle() || includesVacation)` ("doesn't include title or location"), which are semantically equivalent:

```js
let data = [ { title: "Vacation", revenue: 23421 }, { title: "Hospitals", revenue: 34212 }, { title: "Tourism", revenue: 42124 }, {title: "International Tourism", revenue: 87321 } ];

// filter for items where item doesn't include 'tourism' or 'vacation'
newData = data.filter(
  // using ! to exclude any that match:
  item => !(
    // Tourism, OR
    item.title.includes('Tourism') ||
    // Vacation
    item.title.includes('Vacation')
  )
);

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: This is what I was expecting, thank you! will accept your answer once the time limit is over.

Comment: No worries. To elaborate a bit on what happened, you were basically checking if `String.includes == 'Tourism'`, which would never be true (or false, in your case, since it was negated, so it always returned true). `console.log(item.title.includes)` would print something like `function() { [native code] }`, because you would be referring to the method `String.prototype.include` itself. Just for all the gory details.

Comment: I appreciate the details. In the event of checking multiple conditions, for example eliminating `'Tourism`' and` `'Vacation'` adding a `||` to the code you provided returns back the original `data` array. Am I approaching that next step the wrong way?

Comment: @maimok I actually messed up in one of my edits, I had it filtering *for* items with "Tourism" in the title. Adding `!` inverted it. If you edit your question and tag me, I will edit my answer and expand on the use case. If you wanted to exclude anything that contained "Tourism" or "International", you'd do `item => !(item.title.includes('Tourism') || item.title.includes('Vacation'))`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I had edited the code snippet above to include an `"Tourism"` or `"Vacation"` when expanding on the text you had provided it does not filter out the second part `Vacation` when adding an `!item.title.includes('Vacation')` it returns the original array with both Tourism and Vacation. This is where I am currently stuck at

Comment: @maimok I edited. It helps to sound your logic out loud: `filter for items where item doesn't include 'tourism' or 'vacation'`.